# Evento al dar click con Javascript, css, html y jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Como se llama el modo en que hace el cuadro con la imagen

contexto: al hacer click en algun edificio que aparece en el mapa va a aparecer una foto de la oficina con una descripcion

No se como hacer esto ya que apenas soy tecnico en desarrollo de software y nunca he tratado con esto

[image: Como habia dicho en la imagen aparecen varias ciudades y al seleccionar la ciudad quiero que me aparezca un cuadro con una imagen y una descripcion de ella]

Comment: no se como se llama, pero puedes buscarlo en: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/, de seguro lo encuentras

Comment: ¿un modal?  ¿un popup?  Supongo que te refieres a esos nombres

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer en darle un id o clase para todos los botones que mostraran una imagen o texto, ejemplo:

```
<button id="Oficinas">value</button> 
<button id="Oficinas">value1</button> 
<button id="Oficinas">value2</button>
```

y en el script:

```
const DataOficinas = {
value:'El valor de value',
value1:'El valor de 1',
value2:'El valor de 2'
}
function handleSubmit(e){
let seleccion =e.target.innerText
console.log(DataOficinas[seleccion])
}
const Oficinas = document.querySelectorAll('#Oficinas')
Oficinas.forEach(Oficina => 
Oficina.addEventListener('click',handleSubmit))
```

y lo pintas en un html y se cambiará cada vez que cambie el valor, talvez haya mejores soluciones pero esta es la mia, espero poder haberte ayudado